# Query to XML conversion

Tags: php, postgresql

Note: I'm a PHP-noob.

I have a PostgreSQL database running on my server. I just created all my tables and inserted some test data.

I want to execute a query and create a result in XML so my Android Application can read it. First I wanted to create the xml manually but I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087460/transforming-results-of-postgresql-query-to-xml-using-php-dom) and I read [Mapping Tables to XML](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING). I only didn't find any examples/tutorials for this function. I tried this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM query_to_xml('SELECT * from class_levels',true,false,'')";
$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");
```

But I keep getting errors:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: function query_to_xml("unknown", boolean, boolean, "unknown") does not exist HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. in /home/.../cms/index.php on line 18
Cannot execute query: SELECT * FROM query_to_xml('SELECT * from class_levels',true,false,'')
```

What am I doing wrong? And does anyone have some good examples for this function?

Comment: Slightly related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39365/transform-xpath-map-into-xml-document-using-relational-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM query_to_xml('SELECT 1 as foo',true,false,'') x;
                               x                               
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 <table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">↵
                                                              ↵
 <row>                                                        ↵
   <foo>1</foo>                                               ↵
 </row>                                                       ↵
                                                              ↵
 </table>                                                     ↵

(1 row)
```

Your query looks well, so probably you use too old PostgreSQL version without xml support. What pg do you use?

Comment: That's possible, I use PostgreSQL 8.1.23